# homomorphism of fundamental groups induced by a map of two surfaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, surfaces

I am trying to find another proof of the following theorem

**Theorem**
Let $X$ and $Y$ be two compact surfaces of genus greater than $2$. Then
every homomorphism $π_1(X,x_0)→π_1(Y,y_0)$ is induced by a map $(X,x_0)→(Y,y_0)$
that is unique up to homotopy fixing $x_0$ .

In fact a general case of this is proved in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology (Proposition 1B.9. page 90).  He uses CW-complexes and $K(G,n)$ spaces to prove this theorem.

Is there any other way to prove this theorem (without CW-complexes and $K(G,n)$ spaces)?

Comment: What's wrong with CW-complexes?

Comment: @tomasz Nothing is wrong with CW-complexes.  I am just looking for another way (perhaps elementary) to look at this theorem.